# django admin need full table

Tags: python, django, admin

I have only one (first - username) column of my database displayed in admin. How can I display all columns in "Select  to change" panel, like on the picture? Thanks in advance!

[need like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vFMW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model admin, set [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) to the list of fields that you want to display.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['field_1', 'field_2', ...]

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

[ModelAdmin.list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```